# How to bring activity to front from notification in drag down menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-notifications

I am working at an application that uses a notification(with a foreground service).

The use case is the following:

- If the activity of the application is *killed*, when clicking on the notification's icon the activity is created and brought to foreground.
- If the activity of the application is *not visible*, when clicking on the notification's icon the activity is simply brought to foreground.

For re-creating/bringing the activity on foreground I am using the following broadcast receiver in my foreground service:

```
private static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            .setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN")
            .addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        context.startActivity(sIntent);
    }
}
```

The desired action is pretty much similar to the default music player on an android phone, i.e: when clicking on the icon it's activity is simply brought to foreground(or re-created and brought to foreground in case it was previously killed)

This a screenshot from a Samsung S4

[image: Teh screenshot]

- first notification is from usb - we do not care about it
- second notification is my application - **when clicking on the icon the activity gets created but not brought to foreground**(the user has to swipe back the menu to see the activity)

**How can I bring it to front without the additional swipe-back-menu?** (in the similar way how music player app does?

PS: Minimum Android SDK  version is 16

Comment: As far as i know, theres no possibility to bring your activity in front of the notification menu. But you're able to close the menu automatically with: Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(i);

Comment: @Muffin Adding your code before my intent works in a similar way to the music player I mentioned above. May you please answer the question so I can marked it as responded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, theres no possibility to bring your activity in front of the notification menu. But you're able to close the menu automatically with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS); 
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```